# Is there a specific word for "read in silence"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example,

> Instead of reading the poem aloud, they ___ it after the librarian yelled at them.

Synonyms that imply or connote silence usually also imply a level of attention, e.g. *peruse*, *flip through*.

Is there a single word to specify simply reading without making any sound?

Comment: You’re already using multiple words with “reading ... aloud”. You can do the same with “read ... silently”.

Comment: _Subvocalize_ can be considered but it is not common in everyday speech and it is used in technical context also. It is usually used for the internal speech. [_Lexico_](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/subvocalize) definition: "Utter or form (words or sounds) with the lips silently or with barely audible sound, especially when talking to oneself, memorizing something, or reading."

Comment: Yeah no. Do not use "subvocalize". Use "read silently".

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/peruse

Answer (score 1):

Yes one word for "read in silence" exists. You can try 'subvocalize'; it's available in Collins dictionary and the free dictionary. Give it a shot.

Comment: Hello, John. This has already been addressed and dismissed; it would be hugely inappropriate in OP's context.